# Sub domain of .onion is allowed officialy?

Tags: configuration, onion-services

I've got this working link from my friend.
And I'm interested in use 2nd level(sub) domain for my own.
Where's the official Tor statement that subdomain of onion is allowed?

working link:

> "NoMercy Easylist / NoMercy Easyprivacy"
>
> http://repo.a2af37vnxe44tcgo.onion/data/abl/adblock.html

Answer (score 3):

It works in web browsers. Tor daemons will ignore subdomains, but browsers will pass them along in Host headers in the usual way.